# How to extract simple shapes from a feature map?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I am working on image parsing project. I want to find a way to automatically parse an object into a list or a graph of simpler shapes. Is there any practical information on how to do so?

So far I took pre-trained VGG19 model and extracted feature maps of the first convolutional layer. For this purpose I took an image of a bicycle as an example, because it has a pretty simple structure of basic shapes (lines, circles).

The feature maps look like this[image]

The convolutional layer already picked up the shape of the bicycle. The question is how to parse one or multiple of these feature maps into their constitutent simpler shapes (primitives)?

Any advice would be really appreciated. Thanks!